# How to open route as modal on Desktop but page on mobile in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am using the [@nuxtjs/router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/router) module for defining custom routes. Here is my router.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import News from '~/pages/News'
import Login from '~/pages/auth/Login'
import Signup from '~/pages/auth/Signup'
import Account from '~/pages/Account'

Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Index',
        component: News,
      },
      {
        path: '/news',
        name: 'News',
        component: News,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:tag',
        name: 'TaggedNews',
        component: News,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:id([a-f0-9]{32})/:title',
        name: 'NewsItem',
        component: News,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:tag/:id([a-f0-9]{32})/:title',
        name: 'TaggedNewsItem',
        component: News,
      },
      {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
      },
      {
        path: '/signup',
        component: Signup,
      },
      {
        path: '/account',
        component: Account,
      },
    ],
  })
}
```

I want to **open the /login route** as a modal on Desktop but page on mobile. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer would be you can't, as for using a modal you need to tell the app what "actual route" you are on - imagine navigating directly to `/login` on desktop and the issue becomes clear.

My suggestion would be to not add a route for login, but to use a query Param for whether or not the Login modal should be displayed:

- query Param would be handled by a LoginModal component on the app root
- closing/opening would both trigger and  be managed by changes to the query parameter

On mobile, the modal can be styled as a full screen block.

Comment: ok i explored all possible options and i guess only 2 are available, one is to make it a child route which i am not doing as it doesnt make sense /login is not a child of anything, other is to do what you say but my only issue with that is the URL, never seen anyone put a query url for login and SEO takes a hit, in order for a /login to be treated as a modal i guess i will need to let it be handled by the same page that is handling the remaining routes which is News in my case, then perhaps I could do $route.name == 'News' modal is ON else OFF will try this out and post my solution if it works

Comment: You shouldn't care about SEO, I'd say - if login is a modal then it isn't a "page" - the page is News (which gets SEO properly, as long as it has SSR) or any public page (I'm guessing the reason you want a modal is so it is able to be opened in any public page?)
My question is - why do you need SEO for a login page, which is "not a page"?

Comment: login page will have a higher dropout rate, login modal wont besides the similar websites  in my niche all have a modal

Comment: I get all that - what I mean is you SEO the pages where the modal is, not the login page (again, technically, it doesn't exist, it's a Modal)